# I am trying to create a slash animation for my sword, but it does not play

Tags: roblox

I am new to animating in roblox studio and I was able to create a working equip animation. However, when the sword is equipped, and I left-click, it does not do anything, even though I have coded it to play the sword animation. Here is my code:

```
local Sword = script.Parent

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local char = plr.Character
    print(char)
    Sword.Activated:Connect(function()
        print("goi")

        local animation = script:WaitForChild("SwordAnimation")
        local track = char.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
        track:Play()
    end)
    
end)
```

It also will not print my character, or run the print statement inside the activated function.
Sword is the tool, and I have this as a regular script and the equip one is a local, and I included the Sword Animation as well all within the "Sword" tool